# Backup/restore shared preferences android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I'm trying to backup/restore shared preferences of my app, I followed this step using Android Backup Service:

In `Manifest.xml` in `<application>` tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="My Key" />
```

added this class:

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // The name of the SharedPreferences file
    static final String PREFS = "my_preferences";


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
        addHelper(Utilities.SETTINGS_KEY, helper);
    }

}
```

when set value to shared preference I do this:

```
BackupManager backupManager = new BackupManager(context);
backupManager.dataChanged();
```

But if I uninstall/reinstall app, changes doesn't apply...

Comment: I think you need to also have android:allowBackup="true" in your <activity> tag in AndroidManifest

Comment: It wasn't clear from your description. But can you check if you have this in your Manifest  

    `<manifest ... >
          <application android:label="MyApplication"
                 android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent">
          </application>
    </manifest>`

Comment: @pellucide already do!

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you forgot to add

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

inside your `<application>` tag in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file

Comment: No, I've added this

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent like this:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    FileBackupHelper helper = new FileBackupHelper(this,
            TOP_SCORES, PLAYER_STATS);
    addHelper(FILES_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
}
```

and also consider overriding onBackup() and onRestore() methods.
See explanation here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup.html#BackupAgentHelper

Answer (score 1):

when you call `dataChanged()` you just notify system that something is changed, it does not start backup in this moment, give it some time and wi fi connection. Check in your device's settings under '*Backup and reset*' if '*automatic restore*' is set.

Make sure that you writing to the same preferences (with the same key) which you are saving `context.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have setting something like this (depends on android version and even on the device)

> "Cloud and Accounts"->"Backup and Restore"->"Automatic restoration"

turned on. If not, turning it on may solve your problem.